# What are these green pigs with red mustaches?

Tags: angry-birds

What are the green pigs with red mustaches?  Are they different in any way from standard pigs?  What are they based on?

Comment: Send us a picture of it

Answer (score 7):

They seem to be "General / Admiral" pigs.  I get the impression they're somehow Prussian.

They take slightly more effort to kill (more force, or more minor hits) than the regular pigs.  In turn the king pig takes the most effort to kill (partially due to the protective effect of the crown).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the Forman/Mustache Pig takes more hits to kill than Corporal/Helmet Pig, but less than King Pig. You can kill him in one hit with Bomb's explosion, Chuck when he is speeding, Matilda's Egg Bomb, Terrence, Hal while boomeranging, and Bubbles's puff-up ability. It is harder to kill him with Red or The Blues or Stella. He is King Pig's second in command.